# How do I log everything with sentry/raven-js

Tags: javascript, logging, web, sentry

I'm working on an existing project, with a lot of webpages. My task is to introduce logging og client script errors, usingsentr/raven-js.

In the docs, it says that i need to wrap the functions that I need to track in try/catch blocks - this is familiar to me, since I usually work in C#. But I don't wat to edit alle pages to wrap ALL javascript functions in try/catch. Is there a way to log ALL errors?

I tried something with `window.onError = Raven.process`, but I didn't get any logentries.

Can someone show me a what I'm missing? My setup is this:

```
var options = {
    logger: 'my-test-logger',
    whitelistUrls: [
        /localhost/,
        /localhost:2109/
    ]
};
Raven.config('https://<public-key-removed>@app.getsentry.com/<project-key-removed>', options).install();
window.onerror = Raven.process;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My setup was correct, except for the line:

```
window.onerror = Raven.process
```

For some reason I couldn't provoke any error to fire the logging event, but once I managed to simulate a real error, the logging worked just fine. The line:

```
Raven.config('https://@app.getsentry.com/', options).install();
```

does catch all errors.

Comment: +1. And in addition to this answer, Raven only caught those **Uncaught Exceptions**. Those uncaught exceptions triggered in console are also ignored by Raven.

Answer (score 5):

It is important to realize that raven does not capture errors you trigger with the console.  You need to put some error generating code directly in the page, or do something like this from the console:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ foo() });
```

Also, i think that doing:

```
window.onerror = Raven.process
```

Is unnecessary, Raven already does that for you, in a much more advanced way.

Comment: You're from the heaven! 

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to disable logs from raven.js

```
Raven.config('your dsn', {
  autoBreadcrumbs: {
    console: false
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Raven will from version 1 log all window.onerror errors by default.

See https://raven-js.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/index.html#collectwindowerrors

Comment: dead link.  nonetheless, here is the code: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js/commit/8b5236475e9ccdf9d54eff1b7ff7af04cb19b274